# MySQL order by keyword not working with insert into table from the inner join of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-insert

Such is my MySQL query and the order by keyword isnt working here. Cannot figure out what's wrong with it.

```
insert into leaderboard 
select student.student_name as name , sum(marks) as total 
from marks inner join student on student.student_id = marks.student_id 
group by marks.student_id order by total desc;
```

[leaderboard table output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgsi7.png)

Comment: Your current insert might already be working (though it has problems).  What is the exact error message, so that we know how to help you?

Comment: @HoneyBadger please recheck the query statement.

Comment: @MohitKumar please reply to Tims question

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is the output table (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgsi7.png) here the table isnt stored in desc order;

Comment: @HoneyBadger have a look of the output table..

Comment: Please post output such as your table in text form, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current insert is not far off, though as a matter of practice, you should always explicitly list out the target columns for insertion, i.e. use this version:

```sql
INSERT INTO leaderboard (name, total)   -- or whatever the column names are called
SELECT s.student_name, SUM(m.marks)
FROM marks m
INNER JOIN student s ON s.student_id = m.student_id
GROUP BY s.student_id;
```

Regarding the order you do or don't perceive in the `leaderboard` table, appreciate that SQL tables are modeled after *unordered* sets of data.  That is, there is not really any inherent order in a SQL table.  If you want to view your data in a certain order, then use an `ORDER BY` clause when you query (not when you insert):

```sql
SELECT name, total
FROM leaderboard
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for answering my query but it seems that maybe I wasn't much clear in asking. So the thing is I want to store data into descending order on the basis of total in leaderboard table (just like typical leaderboards). Is that possible?

Comment: @MohitKumar No, it's _not_ possible, as my answer explains.  The closest thing perhaps to what you have in mind might be to add an index on `total` to the leader board table.  But, the clustered index (original table) should always be treated as not sorted, and not sortable.